# Apache:How to config for php-cgi.exe

Tags: php, apache-2.4, cgi, php-cgi

I have configured apache for using `php-cgi` as follows:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-handler .php
    Action cgi-handler /local-bin/php-cgi.exe
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But since the accessibility of `php-cgi.exe` requires to have permission, I have used the following block:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/bin/php7">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Will this cause any security problem? If yes, then what is the solution?